# Django file processing app

Tags: django, file-upload

I am looking to write a Django app that is a utility.

I would like the user to be presented  with a form when they can upload 4 or 5 files.
They would then be able to hit a process button and the 5 files would be processed and combine  or zipped and downloaded as 1 file(result_file)

After this the 5 file would be deleted as well at the result_file

I would prefer to avoid having a database on this app as it never really stores ant information

Could all this be done in a view ? and how would you guys approach it ?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: LOL... Yeah tried one, but created a model for the files which didn't work out like I wanted because we landed up with a redundant database. I have never build a django app that doesn't have the database component, so I am struggling with the concept as well as the idea of using temporary storage and using the temp storage to generate a result.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try:

1. Create the script that does the file processing work.
2. You can place the script in a newly created folder inside the django app folder and just import it in your views.py.
   You can create an empty file ,"*init*.py" in the aforementioned new folder, and make it as package to import it in views.py
3. In the same views.py, there could be another function that has the download feature .